# Python - OpenCv - Gradient computing

Tags: python-3.x, gradient, opencv3.0

I've download the opencv from https://opencv.org/opencv-demonstrator-gui/ to make some live test on some images.
I found that this filter work perfectly for my needs:
[image]

, 
I need to code it in my python script, tried to follow this tutorial :https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/d2c/tutorial_sobel_derivatives.html

but I'm unable to find and match setting I need (pre-filtering Deriche, or Schar operator type).
I guess also I should use this syntax:

```
cv.Sobel(gray, ddepth, 1, 0, ksize=3, scale=scale, delta=delta, borderType=cv.BORDER_DEFAULT)
```

Thx.

#### UPDATE

Using this lines I'm close to right result:

```
    scale = 1
    delta = 0
    ddepth = cv2.CV_16S
    src = cv2.imread(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    src = cv2.GaussianBlur(src, (3, 3), 0)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    grad_x = cv2.Sobel(gray, ddepth, 1, 0, ksize=3, scale=scale, delta=delta, borderType=cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
    # Gradient-Y
    # grad_y = cv.Scharr(gray,ddepth,0,1)
    grad_y = cv2.Sobel(gray, ddepth, 0, 1, ksize=3, scale=scale, delta=delta, borderType=cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
    abs_grad_x = cv2.convertScaleAbs(grad_x)
    abs_grad_y = cv2.convertScaleAbs(grad_y)
    grad = cv2.addWeighted(abs_grad_x, 0.5, abs_grad_y, 0.5, 0)
```

Comment: The Schar edge detector is already implement in OpenCV. See https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gaa13106761eedf14798f37aa2d60404c9

Answer (score 3):

You are only doing the X derivative Sobel filter in Python/OpenCV. It is likely you really want the gradient magnitude, not the X directional derivative. To compute the magnitude, you need both the X and Y derivatives and then compute the magnitude. You also like will need to compute as float so as not to get one sided derivatives. You can later convert the magnitude to 8-bit if you want.

```
gradx = cv2.Sobel(gray,cv2.CV_64F,1,0,ksize=3)
grady = cv2.Sobel(gray,cv2.CV_64F,0,1,ksize=3)
gradmag = cv2.magnitude(gradx,grady)
```

The Scharr is similar and can be found at https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gaa13106761eedf14798f37aa2d60404c9

Comment: Thx, what about the Deriche pre-filtering? is it something viable with a function? I'm unable to find it. many thx

Comment: What is Deriche "pre-filtering"? I know about the Deriche edge filter from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deriche_edge_detector. But that is an IIR filter and so there are iterations involved. There is no built-in OpenCV method that I know about.

Comment: I'm just referring to the OpenCV demo tool, and it's reported as parameter. I'm basically trying to re-create same setting from the tool into python script

Comment: What is the link to the demo tool?